# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.urls' the second one although i am a different person

Tags: python

I seem to be having a problem similar to another person from last year with the same title as mine, I did use the search feature to try and see if it was fixed before however it looked like the person stopped and it was never completed.

Here is what leads to what i believe is my problem

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

this is the code that is from the book im studying from and I have narrowed it down to  the code `path('users/', include('users.urls'))` the users.urls it seems is what i believe is causing the problem and it is what leads the server to come up with the error that is in the title

Comment: Is there a directory called `users` with a file called `urls.py` in your project? If not, that's the reason for the exception.

Comment: yes there is a file called users and yes it has urls.py in it, it is just not the url that i have shown. the reason for that is because i cant move the file to the users file because then it asks says it cant find learning logs. url  which is the 3 code in the file

Comment: also i forgot to say and i apologize for it this is from ch. 19 in the setting up a User account ini the python crash course book 2nd edition

Comment: I found the problem thank you for your help